# Not displaying data from a dataset properly in a table, while using a for loop to generate table and cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop

I have a dataset that I am using to create an html table with a loop. I am able to populate the cells with the subjects from the dataset but its not laying out properly.
When I run it the table is showing the subjects as

```
Subject1 Subject1 Subject1
Subject2 Subject2 Subject2
Subject3, Subject3, Subject3
```

and I'm trying to get it look like,

```
Subject1 Subject2 Subject3
Subject4 Subject5 Subject6
Subject7 Subject8 Subject9
```

My code is..

```
// Current row count.
        int rowCtr;
        // Total number of cells per row (columns).
        int cellCtr;
        // Current cell counter.
        int cellCnt;

        //count number of rows in dataset
        int rN = test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

        cellCnt = 3;

        for (rowCtr = 1; rowCtr <= rN; rowCtr++)
        {
            // Create a new row and add it to the table.
            TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);

            for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= cellCnt; cellCtr++)
            {
                // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

                // Add a literal text as control.
                string myStr = test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr -1]["SubjectName"].ToString();

                tCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(myStr));

            }
        }
```

I know this is basic but I haven't used a for loop to do this before.

( Just a side note, I have the rowCtr with a -1 when going through the dataset because if not it throws an error )

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong in my loop to get the layout that I need?, I'm guessing it is something simple that I am missing..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, you are repeating same data three times. Increase the rowcounter once you read a row, like this:

```
string myStr = test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr -1]["SubjectName"].ToString();
rowCtr++;
```

**EDIT :** Regarding your second question in the comment, Index is 0 based and Count is always `LastIndex + 1`.

When you do like this:

```
int rN = test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
```

then the last row you can access is `rN - 1`, actually you are doing this here: `test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr -1]["SubjectName"].ToString();`.

The code above should work fine, you can test replacing `rowCtr` by 1 to 7.

Comment: This works, but when I remove the -1 from rowCtr it throws an error saying there is nothing in the 7th position and I know very well that there is because theres only 7 records and only 6 will appear. I'm not sure if this counts as part of the question but is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: Index is 0 based. Count is always lastindex + 1. So, you can change  this :`int rN = test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows.Count;` to this: `int rN = test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows.Count -1;` or do as you are doing now.

Comment: That is a good reminder for the difference between an Index and a Count. I remembered that arrays start their count at 0, but didn't know the Count lastindex is a +1, Why is this though? is there some reason why a Count is set like that?

Comment: Count will count all items in a collection. For 1 item, index = 0,count=1, for 2 items, last item index is 1, count is 2. for n item, last item index should be n-1 (as we saw for other items), count = n. So, Count = last index + 1. Not sure if the explanation is clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

Your nested for loop executing for three times but here:

```
test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr -1]["SubjectName"].ToString();
```

You always getting same value.So your values are repeating three time.Check your value and try again.

Try this one:

```
for (rowCtr = 0; rowCtr < rN; rowCtr+=3)
    {
        // Create a new row and add it to the table.
        TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
        Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);
        int temp = rowCtr;
        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            if(temp >=rN) break;
            // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
            TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

            // Add a literal text as control.
            string myStr = test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows[temp]["SubjectName"].ToString();

            tCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(myStr));
            temp++;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit of your answer, it works in the same way as the other answer. But this throws the same error as I mentioned in my comment on the other answer. Throws an error saying there is no row in the 7th position and I know that there is, do you have an idea why?

Comment: I added an if statement to nested loop.try again,it throws exception because array index are zero based.probably you have just seven rows,so the last row is row[6]

Comment: That's throwing the same error with the added if statement, and then its throwing all the count off, I will go to the fifth record then restart again from the third record then throws the error again about no row being at position 7, and I even add a -1 to the rN and it will throw the error, the rN is correct of 7 records